# "On the shoreline," "at the shoreline," "by the shoreline." What's the difference?

Tags: grammar

Example:

> He was standing on the shoreline.
>
> He was standing at the shoreline.
>
> He was standing by the shoreline.

What's the difference between the three?

Comment: Not very much difference at all – not with three mundance sentences like those. Without any further context, I'd say they are pretty much interchangeable. If you want to get into any subtle nuances or differences between these three prepositions, you'd have to add a lot more detail; even then, they might still be largely interchangeable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we use this definition of [shoreline](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/shoreline), then:

> He was standing **on** the shoreline.

This is OK because we are standing on top of a surface, though *on* could have other meanings such as *along*.

> He was standing **at** the shoreline.

Means the same thing but it refers to location (where the water meets the land).

> He was standing **by** the shoreline.

Somewhere nearby or close to the shoreline.

Comment: -1 for _on_ is "automatically correct because we are standing on top of a surface."  Sure, "on the shoreline" is correct, but we miss one very important point here: _on_ has more meanings than "on top of" – [many](http://www.onelook.com/?w=on&ls=a) more meanings, in fact. In this case, "standing on the shoreline" is correct, not because he is **on top of** the shoreline, but because he is standing **close to or alongside of** the shoreline; see Meaning #4 at [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/on). If _on_ means "on top of," then what does "a house on the ocean" mean?

Comment: @J.R. OK I made some edits.